# log4net 2.0.8 pattern for client ip address

Tags: log4net, ip-address

I tried to log ip address of the incoming request. I tried following configuration but it does not working for me its log in as "DEBUG".

Global.aspx

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["addr"] = Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

RollingFileAppender

```
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p{addr} %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
        </layout>
```

Log look like this

```
DEBUG 2018-11-20 06:22:50,328 [40] DEBUG Conference - loging successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lowercase `%p` is a shortcut for `%level`.

To output a custom property, you should use **uppercase `%P`**

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%P{addr} %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
</layout>
```

or the **full keyword `%property`**

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%property{addr} %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
</layout>
```

More info at the `Log4net` [reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html).

Comment: Hi, As i am using BeginRequest method in global asax file to log the ip address of the incoming request. However its seems not working perfectly, because when multiple users interact with application and then different ip addresses logged in the file for same users.  void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["addr"] = Request.UserHostAddress;
    }

Comment: 85.24.130.107 2018-11-29 09:55:44,061 [44] DEBUG Conference - Gustav: Debit Token: 1688478159 ddReservations_SelectedIndexChanged end
213.136.59.97 2018-11-29 09:55:47,343 [9] DEBUG Conference - Gustav: Debit Token: 1688478159 btnSave_Click start

Comment: Can't explain, but is not related to the `%P` marker, but to the value that gets assigned to the `addr` entry via `Request.UserHostAddress`. Stuff for an other question.

Comment: Try to assign to [`LogicalThreadContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.LogicalThreadContext.html) via `LogicalThreadContext.Properties["addr"] = Request.UserHostAddress`. Might be a thead reuse side effect.

Comment: i think different thread create problem now if multiple threads created for same user and ip for some threads are null. have a look

Comment: 213.136.59.97 2018-11-30 07:35:33,561 [14] DEBUG Conference - Kitty: visaBoka LoadPrintTimeline end: 
(null) 2018-11-30 07:36:37,968 [32] DEBUG Conference - Kitty: Statistik btnVisa_Click started

Comment: Interesting find. Can you open a new question?  It will be `log4net.LogicalThreadContext`/`ThreadContext` related, not `%P`.

Comment: new question created. I mistakenly create answer instead of question.

Comment: hi pfx, have you figureout what will the problem i tried myself but did not succeed yet.

Comment: I noticed your other question about this, but can only advice to use **LogicalThreadContext** instead; `log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["addr"] = Request.UserHostAddress;`. Similar questions have this marked as an answer.